# Update using a case statement with exists/not exists

Tags: sql, databricks

I'm trying to update a field in a table using the following logic

For the population of Eligible undertake the following calculation:
•   If Record found in Partner_Priority where MCT.Partner = Part-ner_Priority.Partner_ID where status = ‘Include’ and MCT.Status in (0,0S,0Z) set El-igible = ‘Y’
•   If Record not found in Partner_Priority where MCT.Partner = Part-ner_Priority.Partner_ID where status = ‘Include’ and MCT.Status = 0S set Eligible = ‘Y’
•   Else set Eligible = ‘N’

So far I have tried various combos of code, but always end up errors, IN/EXISTS predicate sub queries can only be used as a filter. The code I'm using i've written is as follows. I'm sure it going to be just simple fix, but it's driving me mad, any help would be appreciated

```
    --
    -- Update Eligible field
    --
    -- update mc
    update $env_tech_db.tbl_tech_mpxn_cohort  mc
    set eligible =  case when exists (select * from $env_tech_db.tbl_tech_mct mct
                               inner join $env_tech_db.tbl_tech_partner_priority pp
                               on mct.partner = pp.partner_id
                               where mc.mpxn = mct.mpxn and pp.status = 'Include' and mct.status     in ('0','0S','0Z')) then 'Y' 
                         when not exists(select * from $env_tech_db.tbl_tech_mct mct
                               inner join $env_tech_db.tbl_tech_partner_priority pp
                               on mct.partner = pp.partner_id
                               where mc.mpxn = mct.mpxn and pp.status = 'Include' and mct.status in ('0')) then 'Y'
                        else 'N'
                       end
     --from $env_tech_db.tbl_tech_mpxn_cohort mc
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: Found an aggregate expression in a correlated predicate that has both outer and local references, which is not supported yet. Aggregate expression: count((IF((((mc.`mpxn` = mct.`mpxn`) AND (pp.`status` = 'Include')) AND (mct.`status` IN ('0', '0S', '0Z'))), 1, CAST(NULL AS INT)))), Outer references: mc.`mpxn`, Local references: mct.`mpxn`, pp.`status`, mct.`status`.;;

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-update-join/) for an update with a join. Otherwise you could use a [merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) statement, with just the update part and not the insert part. That might be easier to write.

It could look like this:

```
update mc
set eligible = case when pp.partner_id is not null then 'Y' when pp2.partner_id is null then 'N' end
from

$env_tech_db.tbl_tech_mpxn_cohort  mc
left join $env_tech_db.tbl_tech_mct mct 
on mc.mpxn = mct.mpxn 
left join $env_tech_db.tbl_tech_partner_priority pp
on mct.partner = pp.partner_id

left join $env_tech_db.tbl_tech_mct mct2 
on mc.mpxn = mct2.mpxn
left join $env_tech_db.tbl_tech_partner_priority pp2
on mct2.partner = pp2.partner_id

where pp.status = 'Include' and mct.status     in ('0','0S','0Z')) 
and pp2.status = 'Include' and mct2.status in ('0')
```

The problem you're having is that the table you're updating is also used in a join. (or in this case, reference in the where clause of the exists subquery)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think databricks supports such complicated expressions.  You can use two updates:

```
update $env_tech_db.tbl_tech_mpxn_cohort mc
    set eligible = 'N';

update $env_tech_db.tbl_tech_mpxn_cohort  mc
    set eligible = 'Y'
    where exists (select 1
                  from $env_tech_db.tbl_tech_mct mct join
                       $env_tech_db.tbl_tech_partner_priority pp
                       on mct.partner = pp.partner_id
                  where mc.mpxn = mct.mpxn and pp.status = 'Include' and
                        mct.status in ('0','0S','0Z')
                 ) or
          not exists (select 1
                      from $env_tech_db.tbl_tech_mct mct join
                           $env_tech_db.tbl_tech_partner_priority pp
                           on mct.partner = pp.partner_id
                      where mc.mpxn = mct.mpxn and pp.status = 'Include' and 
                            mct.status in ('0')
                      ) ;
```

Comment: This one appears to be what I'm looking for, I'll have a play and see what the results are